# Packing NuGet as prerelease while also using IncludeReferencedProjects

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I'm running in to an issue that feels like it should be simple, but I'm struggling to find a resolution. I have a solution with multiple class libraries that depend on shared Project Reference also within the same solution. This example is .NET Framework 4.8.1, but my pipeline template runs for .NET as well.

```
NuGet Packages:

ClassLibrary1.dll
  -> SharedProject.dll

ClassLibrary2.dll
  -> SharedProject.dll
...
```

My current pipeline works for the most part, it allows you to pack and publish prerelease and release versions of the DLLs. However, it ONLY includes "ClassLibrary1.dll" but not "SharedProject.dll"

```
variables:
  PrereleaseVersion: '$(build.buildNumber)-prerelease'
  ReleaseVersion: '$(build.buildNumber)'

...

          - task: NuGetCommand@2
            displayName: 'Pack Prerelease Nuget Package'
            inputs:
              command: pack
              packagesToPack: $(project)
              versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
              versionEnvVar: 'PrereleaseVersion'
```

Turning off versioningScheme and adding includeReferencedProjects, it properly packages both ClassLibrary1.dll and SharedProject.dll, but (from what I can tell by reading the documentation & testing) is that just defaults to "ClassLibrary1.Major.Minor.Build" from the assembly without the ability to add -prerelease. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
          - task: NuGetCommand@2
            displayName: 'Pack Prerelease Nuget Package'
            inputs:
              command: pack
              packagesToPack: $(project)
              versioningScheme: 'off'
              includeReferencedProjects: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with the default settings in [NuGetCommand@2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines).

We can add the input `IncludeReferencedProjects: true` with `versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'` to get it work:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: Nuget pack
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: $(project)
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'PrereleaseVersion'
    includeReferencedProjects: true
```

Alternately, you can follow below steps using the Dotnet pack command.

1. Install [Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage/) NuGet package into the projects you are trying to pack. It allows project reference content to be added to the NuGet-package during pack process.
   [image]
2. Edit the `csproj` files (`ClassLibrary1.csproj` and `ClassLibrary2.csproj` in this sample) and add the `PrivateAssets="all"` attribute to the relevant tag:
   [image]

3.Use [DotNetCoreCLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to run the `dotnet pack` command in your pipeline instead of the NuGetCommand task.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'PrereleaseVersion'
```

Check the results, the NuGet will contain both `ClassLibrary1.dll` and `SharedProject.dll`.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

> I've tried using "includeReferencedProjects: true" with
> "versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'", and it worked as far as publishing
> both prerelease and release, but **it ignored the project dependencies**
> (which lines up according to the documentation: versioningScheme
> Applies automatic package versioning depending on the specified value.
> This string cannot be used with includeReferencedProjects.) The
> problem with the alternative solution is we have a lot of NuGet
> packages, so ideally the pipeline template would handle it without
> needing to modify all projects.

Yes, per the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines) `Automatic package versioning` cannot be used with `includeReferencedProjects`. However, if you just need to include the referenced project `*.dll`, then it's OK to do that.

But in your scenario, the requirement is to include the referenced projects and show them as dependencies. Seems no such a built-in feature for now. There are several tickets talking about this on GitHub (e.g [This one](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891) and the workaround mentioned in [this blog](https://josef.codes/dotnet-pack-include-referenced-projects/)), it seems to be a Nuget issue.

Anyway, according to my test, to achieve your requirement we can also use the `.nuspec` file to pack the package. With the `.nuspec` file we can specify the dependencies and assembly references. See [.nuspec reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) for details.

For example, in my sample project `ClassLibrary1` I created a `.nuspec` file and specify the `SharedProject` as dependency and add [files node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#files) to specify which assembly and content files to include in the package like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$authors$</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <!-- <icon>icon.png</icon> -->
    <projectUrl>$ProjectUrl$</projectUrl>
    <description>$description$ </description>
    <releaseNotes>$releaseNotes$</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>$tags$</tags>
      <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net6.0">
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="SharedProject" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers"/>
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\net6.0\*.dll" target="lib\net6.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then pack the package using the `.nuspec` file with Nugetcommand task:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.nuspec'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'PrereleaseVersion'
    buildProperties: 'id=ClassLibrary1;title=NugetPackDemo;ProjectUrl=$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri);authors=$(authors);copyright=$(copyright);description=$(description);releaseNotes=$(releaseNotes);tags=PackDemo, AndyDemo'
```

And the final results：

[image]

In this way we also need to create `.nuspec` files for the projects. So, I don't think there's a way to achieve your requirements without changing anything in your projects. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried using "includeReferencedProjects: true" with "versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'", and it worked as far as publishing both prerelease and release, but it ignored the project dependencies (which lines up according to the documentation: **versioningScheme Applies automatic package versioning depending on the specified value. This string cannot be used with includeReferencedProjects.**)

The problem with the alternative solution is we have a lot of NuGet packages, so ideally the pipeline template would handle it without needing to modify all projects.

Comment: @Nerrickk I don't think there's a way to achieve your requirements without changing anything in your projects. Please see the updated answer for details.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that. Thanks for the help!